# View dropped, now shows as table "in use", can't drop

Tags: mysql, myisam, view, corruption

I have a view on a MySQL/MyISAM setup, then the underlying table had a column dropped, and made that view invalid.

I tried dropping the view so I could recreate it, then MySQL said it was a table (not a view) and marked it "in use".

Now I can't drop nor repair that table because it says it is not a table.

I've googled for hours trying find a way to fix this :(

I do have root access on the MySQL server running Ubuntu. I stopped MySQL and tried `myisamchk`, but no luck.

I can see a `.frm` file for the view in the db data folder.

Do I need to delete that file to make the corrupt item go away, 
or do I somehow delete the table from the db schema?

I have a db backup from last night, but would rather fix this 1 issue than restore from backup and lose today's changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to simply rename that file to just about *anything* that doesn't end in .frm and then `SHOW TABLES`.  It should be gone.  If it's still there, `FLUSH TABLES`, then `SHOW TABLES` again.